# Convert System collection list <anonymous> to generic list<myviewmodel> ASP.NET-MVC5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working ASP.NET-MVC5 app. I have three model classes, I need to pass model with data from controller to view, so I am using view-Model class to combine all three classes and trying to pass but I am getting error as shown following in screen shot. I need help in method "GetCourseByStudentID"

[image]

### Linq method to read data from database

```
 public List<StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel> GetCourseByStudentID(int _studentID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                var _record = (from _course in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll()
                              join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _course.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                              join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _course.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                              where _course.StudentID == _studentID
                               select new { _course, _school, _campus }).ToList();


                return _record;
            }
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
public class StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel
{
    public StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel() { }

    public Course _courseModel { get; set; }
    public School _schoolModel { get; set; }
    public Campus _campusModel { get; set; }

}
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult EditStudentCourse()
    {
        var _StudentCourseModel = _studentProfileServices.GetCourseByStudentID(6);

        return null; // incomplete 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Select method to generate Entities typed list:

```
    public List<StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel> GetCourseByStudentID(int _studentID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                var _record = (from _course in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll()
                    join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _course.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                    join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _course.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                    where _course.StudentID == _studentID
                    select new { _course, _school, _campus }).ToList();


                var studentsVM = _record.Select(s=> new StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel()
                                          {
                                                 _courseModel = s._course, 
                                                 _schoolModel = s._school, 
                                                 _campusModel = s._campus
                                          }
                );

                return studentsVM;
            }
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

If you want to know how does Select(Func selector) work deeply - here is explanation on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @LeandroSoares it was simultaneously :)

Comment: Many thanks it work... have a look, based on your guide I slighty change my approach

Answer (score 1):

Just use select function

```
public List<StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel> GetCourseByStudentID(int _studentID)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
        {
            var _record = (from _course in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll()
                           join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _course.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                           join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _course.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                           where _course.StudentID == _studentID
                           select new { _course, _school, _campus })
                           .Select(x => new StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel()
                           {
                               CourseId = _course.Id,
                               CourseName = _course.Name,
                               SchoolId = _school.Id
                               ...
                           })
                           .ToList();

            return _record;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//...
var _record = (from _course in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll()
                join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _course.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _course.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                where _course.StudentID == _studentID
                // Here is the problem, you have to specify the type.
                select new StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel { 
                           Course = _course, 
                           School = _school, 
                           Campus = _campus }).ToList();
```

I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks for Andriy guide... I have change slighty and decided to send model of view-model-class instead of list ...

### Funtion to return data

```
 public partial class StudentProfileServices
{
    #region Get Student Course By StudentID
    public StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel GetCourseByStudentID(int _studentID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                var _record = (from _course in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll()
                              join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _course.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                              join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _course.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                              where _course.StudentID == _studentID
                              select new StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel  {_courseModel= _course, _schoolModel = _school, _campusModel = _campus }).FirstOrDefault();

                return _record;
            }
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

### Controller

```
   public ActionResult EditStudentCourse()
    {
        StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel _StudentCourseModel = new StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel();

       _StudentCourseModel = _studentProfileServices.GetCourseByStudentID(6);


        return PartialView("EditStudentCourse_Partial", _StudentCourseModel);
    }
```

### View

```
@model App.DAL.Model.StudentCourseSchoolAndCampusViewModel

<h1>edit student course</h1>

@Model._courseModel.ModeOfStudy  // to test the model data
```